# Cast an object to an array

Tags: java, arrays, reflection, casting

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int[] a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    method(a);
}

public static void method(Object o) {
    if (o != null && o.getClass().isArray()) {
        Object[] a = (Object[]) o;
        // java.lang.ClassCastException: [I cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
    }
}
```

I'm not supposed to know what's the type of the parameter `o` in the `method`. How can I then cast it in an `Object[]` array?

**`instanceof` can't be a solution since the parameter can be an array of any type.**

*PS: I've seen several questions on SO dealing with array casting, but no one (yet?) where you don't know the type of the array.*

Comment: Are you able to provide a little more context to your question. What do you intend to do with these objects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `java.lang.reflect.Array.get()` to get a specific element from your unknown array.

Comment: This will work very slowly due to reflection. But +1 for an idea

Comment: Looking at the tags, I think that is somewhat what he's looking for

Answer (score 5):

You can't cast an array of primitives (`int`s in your case) to an array of `Object`s. If you change:

```
int[] a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

to

```
Integer[] a = new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

it should work.

Comment: If you never pass primitives you will always be able to cast to `Object` and your problem will be solved

Comment: This is incorrect use of object wrappers in arrays. Doing so you produce overheads on memory.

Answer (score 4):

You can not cast this object to `Object[]` class, because actually this is an array of `int`-s. So, it will be correct if you write:

```
public static void method(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof int[]) {
        int[] a = (int[]) o;
        // ....
    }
}
```

Comment: @sp00m, yes, you should. And it isn't something wrong. Look at `java.util.Arrays` class and you will see, that this is a common pattern for primitive types. For example, see method `hashCode` of `java.util.Arrays` class.

Comment: This (and other similar answers) looks the best to me. While it feels *wrong* to pack a method with `if` statements, it's truly necessary if you must take an `Object` as your input.

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**

Use **o.getClass().getComponentType()** to determine what type is it:

```
if (o != null) {
  Class ofArray = o.getClass().getComponentType(); // returns int  
}
```

See [Demo](http://ideone.com/20B9qY)

---

**Option 2**

```
if (o instanceof int[]) {
  int[] a = (int[]) o;           
}
```

*Noice: You can use any type other than int to determine what kind of array is it and cast to it when needed.

Comment: IMHO this is the best answer, it is the question which incorrectly assumes it needs to be cast an `Object[]`

Comment: @sp00m sorry i fixed my answer, you can determine the type without the instanceof option, just use getClass().getComponentType(). See DEMO: http://ideone.com/20B9qY